# How can we detect changes in strings, in multiple columns, and add results to the current dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have this dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# data stored in dictionary
details = {
    'address_id': [111,111,111,111,111,111,222,222,222,222,222,222,333,333,333,333,333,333,444,444,444,444,444,444,555,555,555,555,555,555,777,777,777,777,777,777,888,888,888,888,888,888],
    'my_company':['Comcast','Verizon','Other','Verizon','Comcast','Comcast','Spectrum','Spectrum','Spectrum','Spectrum','Spectrum','Spectrum','Verizon','Verizon','Verizon','Verizon','Verizon','Verizon','Spectrum','Spectrum','Spectrum','Spectrum','Verizon','Spectrum','Spectrum','Spectrum','Spectrum','Spectrum','Verizon','Other','Verizon','Comcast','Comcast','none','none','Verizon','Sprint','Comcast','Comcast','none','none','Verizon'],
    'my_date':['2022-01-24','2022-02-21','2022-03-28','2022-04-25','2022-05-23','2022-06-27','2022-01-24','2022-02-21','2022-03-28','2022-04-25','2022-05-23','2022-06-27','2022-01-24','2022-02-21','2022-03-28','2022-04-25','2022-05-23','2022-06-27','2022-01-24','2022-02-21','2022-03-28','2022-04-25','2022-05-23','2022-06-27','2022-01-24','2022-02-21','2022-03-28','2022-04-25','2022-05-23','2022-06-27','2022-01-24','2022-02-21','2022-03-28','2022-04-25','2022-05-23','2022-06-27','2022-01-24','2022-02-21','2022-03-28','2022-04-25','2022-05-23','2022-06-27']
}

df = pd.DataFrame(details)
df
```

Then I do a simple pivot:

```
pvt = df.pivot(index='address_id', columns='my_date', values='my_company')
pvt = pvt.reset_index()
```

This is what I have now:

[image]

This is what I want to get to:

[image]

The logic that I'm trying to get to, is this:

```
#1) was with Verizon then left and then came back and then left = 'boomerang'

#2) was never with Verizon = 'never customer'

#3) was always with Verizon = 'always customer'

#4) was with Verizon at some point, but not with Verizon in the most recent month = 'previous customer'

#5) was with Verizon at some point, then left, but came back to Verizon in the most recent month = 'left but back'

#6) was not with Verizon before the most recent month but just came to Verizon in the most recent month = 'new customer'
```

I'm thinking it's going to start with something like this...

```
for column in pvt:
    if ('Verizon' not in column):
       pvt['status'] = 'never customer'
```

But, I can tell it's looping through all columns, including the first column, and I don't know how to get this thing to switch back and forth, to find 'boomerang', 'previous customer', 'left but back', and 'new customer'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just follow your logic with `np.select`

```
pvt = df.pivot(index='address_id', columns='my_date', values='my_company')
conda = pvt.iloc[:,-1].eq('Verizon')
condb = pvt.iloc[:,-1].ne('Verizon')

cond1 = pvt.ne('Verizon').all(1)
cond2 = pvt.eq('Verizon').all(1)
cond3 = pvt.eq('Verizon').sum(1)==1
cond4 = pvt.eq('Verizon').sum(1)>1
pvt['new'] = np.select([cond1,cond2,condb&cond3,conda&cond4,conda&cond3],['never','always','pervious','comeback','new'],default = 'boom')
```